# register_activation_hook() to use plugin properties and methods, possible?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I need to set the activation hook `register_activation_hook()` for my plugin.

This is the main file `my-plugin/my-plugin.php`:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin Name
Plugin URI: https://website.com
Description: Plugin Description
*/  
class my_plugin{
    
    function __construct(){ 
        
        $this->main_file = 'my-plugin/my-plugin.php';
        
    }
    
}
$my_plugin = new my_plugin;

require_once 'actions/on-activation.php';
```

Ant this is the file `my-plugin/actions/on-activation.php`:

```
class run_on_activation{

    function __construct(){
        
        global $my_plugin;          
        $file = $my_plugin->main_file;     /* it doesn't work (plugin property) */

        $file = 'my-plugin/my-plugin.php'; /* it works (hardcoded value) */
        
        register_activation_hook( $file, array( $this, 'run' ) );
        
    }
    
    function run(){
        
        // do something
      
    }
    
}
new run_on_activation;
```

My concern is that properties from `my_plugin` cannot be passed to the `run_on_activation` class. Is this because my plugin has not been activated yet? For portability, I would prefer not to hardcode the value.

In between `run_on_activation` class, I would like to be able to use `my_plugin` properties and methods. I am running out of ideas. Is this possible?

Please don't flag my question. Kindly indicate what is wrong and I will amend as soon as possible. Thank you